# Getting a Truth Value Numpy error in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have this portion of code in my script (appended is an image object loaded using the Pillow module):

```
appended_data = np.asarray(appended)
# Find Right Side Vertical
rsv_list = []
for i in range(int(.25 * appended.size[1]), int(.65 * appended.size[1]), 5):
    counter = 0
    for value in appended_data[i][::-1]:
        if value != 255:
            rsv_list = rsv_list + [counter]
            break
        elif counter > 300:
            break
        else:
            counter += 1
```

However when I run this script I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CHOP_CRP_test1_script.py", line 26, in <module>
    if value != 255:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I know that you can get this error with boolean arrays but this numpy array is an array of pixel values. The for loop should be looping backwards through each pixel value in each row. This method worked in the terminal but now it is throwing an error when trying to run it from a script. Could anybody help identify the problem?

Comment: `Value` is an `array` containing one or more elements. Comparing this to an integer or float (in your case 255) is ambiguous since it does not make sense. That's what the error messages tells you. In order to reproduce your error you need to provide `appended_data` and `appended` since your code is not runnable without these variables. As an alternative you could provide a more general example with random arrays using `np.random`

Comment: to elaborate on @albert's comment, if `appended_data` is a matrix of pixel values (or a 3D array where each corresponds with an rgb pixel value), then your `value` object is a numpy array and hence the error. You could either try `if 255 is not in value` or you would have to loop through the `value` array with `if all([x !=225 for x in value])`

Comment: What `appended_data.shape`, and within the loop, what is `value`?  or `value.shape`.  The error suggests that `value` is an array with more than one value.  From this indexing `appended_data[i][::-1]` it is hard to tell what is going on.  `appended_data[i, ::-1,:]` would tell me clearly that the array is at least 3d.